# Is it bad practise to serve an error 403 page for an application-level policy?

Tags: http, web-applications, web

Say I have a website that allows anyone to log in through oauth or similar, but only allows certain uses to create or modify content. Should they somehow make a request for page for creating a new post, I'll do a check and redirect them if they don't have the appropriate permissions.

It is considered acceptable to redirect to the "403 Error" page in this situation? There was no actual HTTP response with a 403 status code, there was no database- or server- level query that was failed - just my business logic. Am I misappropriating the idea of HTTP status codes if I serve an error 403 page with a specific explanatory message?

Comment: As long as your API docs state that's what the client is to expect, it's really up to you.

Comment: I'm just concerned that I'm somehow brutalising REST here.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html simply states that code "403 Forbidden" is the server acknowledging the request was properly formed but the server is refusing to process it. I think this is appropriate with (what I'm assuming is) your ACL policy. I'd just make sure that you send a plaintext response as to why the request is not being processed.

Comment: sorry, I think I misread your question. My suggestion is only applicable if this is a RESTful API. If this is a webpage, then you should return a "200" code and explain on the page that user doesn't have the privileges to perform said action (or just ignore the request and redirect them to some sane default page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to do so, but I think if you want to expose an API you would use an actual 403 response because they carry meaning that will be nicely handled by the client.

If you want to display a page to the client and will be using redirect, you will lose this meaning of the "403".

Isn't it better to just redirect them to an explanation page without including the "403" code. Or better yet, redirect them to a more helpful place, like the sign up page if that is what they have to do to make a post, or back to the original page with a floating message.

We want to help the user get closer to their goals instead of confusing them with technical error codes.

Answer (score 0):

There is often a lot of discussion about this very topic and it comes down to the following choices:

- a 5xx?  Of course not.  This is not a server error.
- a 400?  Not really, it wasn't a *malformed* request.
- a 401?  Probably not, 401 is generally for authorization in general, not application-level permissions.  If your user has already logged in but has the wrong role, and you want to let the user know, then use something else.
- a 404?  Perhaps, as the server can't find the resource for this particular user, but if you want to tell the user "well such a resource is available but *you* can't have it because you lack permissions" then go with something else.
- a 403?  Actually, this one makes a lot of sense.  Here is the definition from the RFC

  > *403 Forbidden* The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

In your question you mention your intention to redirect the user.  If you are making a *RESTFUL web service* then just return the 403.  If you are doing an entire web app, you can control the 403 and redirect....

Comment: The thing that makes 403 iffy is the "Authorization will not help" part -- making it sound unconditional, as opposed to depending on the user's access.  Authorization *would* help if user had the right access, and the request *should* be repeated if the user can supply appropriate credentials.